# Get only atribute from a session and not the id of the atribute

Tags: php, session

I am making some filters on a website and i have to filter the atribute from some datas by session. The example i have is by filtering the atribute and the id and i don't know how to select the atribute and all the ids of his atribute. The code for atribute and what i try to do is like this:

```
  if (isset($_REQUEST['Filtru']) && strpos($_REQUEST['Filtru'], 'atr') === 0) {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['AtributID']) && (int) $_REQUEST['AtributID'] > 0) {               
                    $_SESSION['Catalog']['Filtre']['Atribute']['AtributID'] = $_REQUEST['AtributID'];
                    $_SESSION['Catalog']['Filtre']['Atribute']['Filtru'] = $_REQUEST['Filtru'];
                    $_SESSION['offset'] = 0;
                }
    else {
                    unset($_SESSION['Catalog']['Filtre']['Atribute'][$_REQUEST['Filtru']][-1 * (int) $_REQUEST['AtributID']]);
                }
}
```

And this is how i tried:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['Filtru']) && strpos($_REQUEST['Filtru'], 'atr') === 0) {

            if (isset($_REQUEST['AtributID']) && (int) $_REQUEST['AtributID'] > 0) {               
                $_SESSION['Catalog']['Filtre']['Atribute']['AtributID'] = $_REQUEST['AtributID'];
                $_SESSION['Catalog']['Filtre']['Atribute']['Filtru'] = $_REQUEST['Filtru'];
                $_SESSION['offset'] = 0;
            }

            else if (!isset($_REQUEST['AtributID']) || (int) $_REQUEST['AtributID'] <= 0)  {
                if (isset($_REQUEST['Atribute']) && (int) $_REQUEST['Atribute'] > 0) {
                    $_SESSION['Catalog']['Filtre']['Atribute'] = $_REQUEST['Atribute'];
                    $_SESSION['Catalog']['Filtre']['Filtru'] = $_REQUEST['Filtru'];
                    $_SESSION['offset'] = 0;    
                }

                else {
                    unset($_SESSION['Catalog']['Filtre']['Atribute'][$_REQUEST['Filtru']]);
                }
            }
            else {
                unset($_SESSION['Catalog']['Filtre']['Atribute'][$_REQUEST['Filtru']][-1 * (int) $_REQUEST['AtributID']]);
            }
        }
```

The newt step, to apply the filter, in another function looks like this:

```
 $fstr = '';

        if(isset($_SESSION['Catalog']['Filtre']['Atribute']['AtributID']) && isset($_SESSION['Catalog']['Filtre']['Atribute']['Filtru']))       
        $fstr .= ' '.$_SESSION['Catalog']['Filtre']['Atribute']['Filtru'].' in ('.$_SESSION['Catalog']['Filtre']['Atribute']['AtributID'].')';
```

And mine like this but it gives me errors on the implode function, and it sais that Atribut is undefined:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['Catalog']['Filtre']['Atribute']) && count($_SESSION['Catalog']['Filtre']['Atribute'])) {

           foreach ($_SESSION['Catalog']['Filtre']['Atribute'] as $k => $v) {
               if (count($v)) {

                  if (strlen($fstr))
                       $fstr .= ' AND ';

                  $vals = '(' . implode(',', $v) . ')';
                   $fstr .= " $k in $vals ";                    

                }
            }
```

Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you are trying to do but it seems to me that implode should take an array as second argument ;)

try this instead

```
if (isset($_SESSION['Catalog']['Filtre']['Atribute']) && count($_SESSION['Catalog']['Filtre']['Atribute'])) {
if (count($_SESSION['Catalog']['Filtre']['Atribute'])) {

              if (strlen($fstr))
                   $fstr .= ' AND ';

              $vals = '(' . implode(',', $_SESSION['Catalog']['Filtre']['Atribute']) . ')';

}
```

this way you're passing to implode the array of Atributes cointained in $_SESSION['Catalog']['Filtre']['Atribute']. You don't need to use foreach.